# The word 'Relearn'

Tags: word-usage

I was surprised of not seeing the verb **Relearn** in any of the online dictionaries I use the most: Cambridge, Oxford and MacMillan.

Is it formally correct to use it?

Comment: It's definitely in the online Oxford Dictionary: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/relearn

Comment: Thank you very much! Sorry for the question. I've realised I am using the wrong dictionary: the _Oxford Learner's Dictionary_ http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/. I am going to change it now!

Comment: @viery365: In the case of regularly-formed derivatives like ***wipe => rewipe***, you won't necessarily find them in dictionaries anyway (that one isn't even in the *full* OED, for example). But that doesn't mean they're not valid words.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you! My opinion on this matter is that the dictionaries should have entries for those words (at least the online versions) unless all verbs have the possibility of a regularly-formed derivative re- (which I still do not know). At least, an entry within the meaning of the word giving the info about the re- derivative.

Comment: That's an interesting point about whether *all verbs have the possibility of a regularly-formed derivative*. My first thought was they *do* - assuming there's some context (no matter how contrived) where such a verb could be *semantically* credible. But on reflection I don't think there would be any support for ***rebe, rehave, rego*** etc. Since no-one has yet answered your question here (presumably because it's somewhat trivial - of *course* ***relearn*** would be "valid", regardless of whether you found it in your dictionary), perhaps you might consider editing it...

Comment: ...to ask the more generic question *What (if any) verbs **can't*** be prefixed by **re** or **re-** ?* That might elicit more responses (I certainly don't know the answer to that one! :)

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate your comments and will take in consideration the idea for a better question.

Comment: Here's the question: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/271027/is-there-any-grammar-rule-for-the-usage-of-the-re-prefix